# How to replace special character In Android?

Tags: java, android

I have to create file with user define name. If User can use the special character then i want to replace that special character with my specific string. i found the method like this.

```
String replaceString(String string) {
   return string.replaceAll("special_char","");
}
```

but how to use this method.?

Comment: what is your problem exactly?

Comment: just call `replacedString=replaceString(yourstring);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

relpaceAll method is required regular expression and replace string.

```
string.replaceAll("regularExpression","replaceString");
```

You can use this regular expression :

```
"[;\\/:*?\"<>|&']"
```

e.g.

```
String replaceString(String string) {
   return string.replaceAll("[;\\/:*?\"<>|&']","replaceString");
}
```

Comment: thanks for your instance replay let me check this code.

Answer (score 1):

Try

> regular expression

```
   static String replaceString(String string) {
       return string.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9 ]","");// removing all special character.
    }
```

call

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

     String str=replaceString("Hello\t\t\t.. how\t\t are\t you."); // call to replace special character.
     System.out.println(str);
  }
```

output:

```
Hello how are you
```

Comment: this is work great but if user will enter the other language instead of eng then this code will replace the char of other language. so this "[;\\/:*?\"<>|&']" regular expression work gr8.

Answer (score 0):

use below function to replace your string

```
 public static String getString(String p_value)
 {

        String p_value1 = p_value;
        if(p_value1 != null && ! p_value1.isEmpty())
        {
            p_value1 = p_value1.replace("Replace string from", "Replace String to");
            return p_value1;
        }
        else
        {
            return "";
        }
 }
```

**example**

Replace string from = "\n";
Replace String to   = "\r\n";

after using above function \n is replace with \r\n

Answer (score 0):

**this method make two line your string data after specific word **

```
public static String makeTwoPart(String data, String cutAfterThisWord){
    String result = "";

    String val1 = data.substring(0, data.indexOf(cutAfterThisWord));

    String va12 = data.substring(val1.length(), data.length());

    String secondWord = va12.replace(cutAfterThisWord, "");

    Log.d("VAL_2", secondWord);

    String firstWord = data.replace(secondWord, "");

    Log.d("VAL_1", firstWord);

    result = firstWord + "\n" + secondWord;


    return result;
}
```